# Second order differential forms vanishing?

Tags: differential-forms

I understand $dx dx = 0$ but why can’t we say the same for $dx dy$ as they’re both infinitesimal? I came across this when looking up an alternative derivation of change of variables in several dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are certainly other cases where a differential element squared is formally zero and the intuitive reason is that the square of something small is much smaller, but I don't think that's the most useful way to think about it here.  in In the sense of forms, the reason $dxdx=0,$ isn't because it is infinitesimal. We think of $dx\wedge dy$ intuitively as the area of a parallelogram with sides $dx$ and $dy.$ $dx\wedge dx$ is zero not cause of the infinitesimal-ness but because two parallel vectors make a parallelogram with zero area. In fact, it's generally the case that $v\wedge v=0$ even for non-infinitesimal $v.$ (Except in more exotic cases where the components of $v$ are non-commuting objects rather than numbers.)

[image: The area represented by $dx$ and $dy$]

(Image provided by user Steffen Plunder.)

Comment: Is $dx dy = dx \wedge dy$?

Comment: @Glassjawed yes, the wedges are often omitted for brevity. Also you have $dxdy = -dydx$ so you can see there's something going on there.

Comment: I still don’t understand the intuition for that either. If I integrate over $[a,b]\times [c,d]$, then $\int \int 1 dx\, dy=(b-a)(d-c)=\int \int 1 dy\, dx.$

Comment: @Glassjawed It tells you that if the coordinate system were flipped to right-handed (or you went and looked at the plane from the other side), one of those integrals would be going in the 'negative direction' and have a minus sign.

Comment: @Glassjawed: Before you can turn the integral of $f\,dx\wedge dy$ into a double integral of $f$, you must make sure that the order of the wedge product agrees with the (standard) orientation on $\Bbb R^2$. So $\iint 1\,dy\wedge dx = \iint 1(-dx\wedge dy) = -\iint 1\,dx\wedge dy$, even though Fubini says you can do the iterated integral in either order. You should distinguish here between double integral and iterated integrals.